# HTML change LI size or image

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Given a solitary `<li />` I need to increase it's size.  Font-size works only in firefox, IE just shows it as same size.

Can I change the `LI` size another way, or set it's image?  Please note (and I know this is bad) there is no `UL` element, it is invalid markup as it is part of an older system which the design means the UL can't be added in easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<li>` elements are inline elements so they will get the inner elements' width. You can set display property to "inline-block" and set a width. I guess it will solve your problem.

Comment: Still having trouble with this, I still need the text to the right to be displayed correctly, can you give an example please?

Comment: I just want the LI functioning as normal but the disc shape bigger somehow, your answer leaves me a bit confused I'm afraid!

Comment: if you want li functioning normally you should use it in an unordered list (<ul> element). Default shapes of the lists are different between browsers. If you do not want this to happen you should set list-style-image css property to some image you want.

Comment: Or use spans with your own predefined image created in your favourite image editing software :)

Answer (score 1):

`<li>` is an inline element, you can use `display: inline-block;` to have it accept width, height, background, positioning and other rules, while maintaining its inline flow.

Also you could try using `<span>` with an image of a dot positioned to the left of the text instead of invalid markup.

```
.liSpan
{
   display: inline-block;
   background-image: images/dot.png;
   background.position: left;
   padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Or something similar :)

Comment: Thanks, having trouble still, the text to the right of it doesn't display properly when it wraps on multiple lines!

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't display properly?" What is the effect you'd like to achieve? I think you might be after `background-position: center left;` though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the line-height, or it's padding to increase the height.

```
.liSpan
{
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```